# HA configuration on Compute Engine

Tags: ip, high-availability, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to have something like [this](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/configure-high-avaliablity-cluster-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html) using compute engine? In my case I would like to have an external IP address as a service IP so this IP can be configured in any compute engine VM.

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I searched my notes, and all I found is: **http://googlegenomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases/setup_gridengine_cluster_on_compute_engine/** This is might be not what are you looking but I hope this can help.